# Image not set on the custom button

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have two views.On my 1st view i have one custom button.By clicking on that button the other view will create with Icon library.by clicking on that icon the icon will set to the 1st view.i have store the value into NSUser defaults.but the icon is not set.

here is the code:

view2:

```
 -(IBAction)btnImage1Clicked:(id)sender{

NSString *img1=@"NODE - BOOK_a.png";
NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if (standardUserDefaults) {

    [standardUserDefaults setValue:img1 forKey:@"image1"];
    [standardUserDefaults synchronize];
}
  [img1 release];


[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

}

view1:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSString *val = nil;
NSLog(@"val=%@",val);
NSLog(@"user default=%@",[standardUserDefaults valueForKey:@"image1"]);
if (standardUserDefaults) 
    val = [standardUserDefaults stringForKey:@"image1"];
NSLog(@"image name=%@",val);

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",val]];
 stringWithFormat:@"%@",val]] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
[imageButton setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 

forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"" forKey:@"image1"];
```

}

Comment: I dont know why you are releasing `img1` in view2 when you are not allocating it. Overreleasing is not a good practice. It may lead to crash because of Zombies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think may be Maulik's code is working but I dont think it is a right way to use `setObject:forKey` method for NSString.

There is a basic mistake in the code.

You are allocating  string value to `img1` assigning it to the NSUserDefaults and then releasing the string ultimately that even releases the string in NSUserDefaults as it is not copied.

Is there any reason for releasing `img1` in `view2` when you are not allocating it? Overreleasing is not a good practice. It may lead to crash because of Zombies at some point in time.

So put the code in your `view2` as shown below. i.e. remove the `[img1 release]` statement and it should work fine with your code:

```
-(IBAction)btnImage1Clicked:(id)sender
{

     NSString *img1=@"NODE - BOOK_a.png";
     NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

     if (standardUserDefaults) {

        [standardUserDefaults setValue:img1 forKey:@"image1"];
        [standardUserDefaults synchronize];
     }

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

So the bottom line is you don't need to release `img1` when you are not allocating it.

For more information on memory management, you may refer to [Memory Management Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html)

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

to set string in `NSUserDefaults` try this.

```
NSString *valueToSave = @"someValue";
NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[standardUserDefaults setObject:img1 forKey:@"image1"];
```